# Child elements extend outside parent div: Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap menus which collapse at certain max-widths leaving me with the following results. I am trying to get the sub menu items on the blue navigation bar to overflow in the same way that they do on the purple. Any suggestions?

**Blue menu**

[image: Blue menu]

**Purple menu**

[image: Purple menu]

Purple Menu's CSS

```
nav {
    background-color: #603180;
    z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
}
#toggle {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container {
    background: #603180;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul  .current-menu-item {
    background-color: #00337e;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul  .current-menu-item ul .current-menu-item {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul .current-menu-item a:link {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-weight:700;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container .current-page-parent {
    background-color: #00337e;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container .sub-menu .current-page-parent {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align:left;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease;
    transition: color .2s ease;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: auto;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul li {
    max-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
    background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 15px;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul li a {
    color: #00337e !important;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 25px !important;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color: #603180;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    transition: all 0.15s linear;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul li.active > a {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul li:hover:after,
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul li.active:after {
    background: #4cb6ea;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul li:hover > ul > li {
    max-height: 72px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container.align-center > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container.align-center > ul {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container.align-center ul ul {
    text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container.align-right > ul {
    float: right;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
    right: 100%;
    left: auto;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container.align-right ul ul li a {
    text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background: #00337e;
    -webkit-transition: height .2s;
    -moz-transition: height .2s;
    -ms-transition: height .2s;
    -o-transition: height .2s;
    transition: height .2s;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li.has-sub > a {
    padding-right: 40px;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li:hover:after,
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li.active:after {
    height: 100%;
}       
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li.active > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li.active > a:after {
    background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li:hover > a:before,
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li.active > a:before {
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
    max-height: 72px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container #menu-button {
    display: none;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li {
    width: auto;
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li > ul {
    width: 210px;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
}
#cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container > ul > li > ul > li {
    width: 210px;
    display: block;
}
nav #cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li a:link {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 12px 26px;
}
nav #cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #00337e;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    transition: all 0.15s linear;
}
nav #cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #603180;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    transition: all 0.15s linear;
}

@media (max-width: 979px) { 
    nav { 
        opacity: 0.97;
    }
    #toggle {
        display: block;
        color: #ffffff;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    #toggle h6 {
        font-size: 1.2857142857142858em;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #toggle:after {
        top: 80%;
        left: 50%;
        border: solid transparent;
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        border-top-color: #ffffff;
        border-width: 11px;
        margin-left: -11px;
    }
    nav #cssmenu {
        display: none;
    }
    nav h6 {
        color: #ffffff; 
    }
    nav #cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li ul {
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    nav #cssmenu .menu-main-nav-menu-container ul li {
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Blue Menu's CSS

```
    nav .container {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.navbar .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
    -o-transition: all ease .3s;
    transition: all ease .3s;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu, 
.dropdown:focus .dropdown-menu {    /*allows hover dropdown*/
    display: block;
 }
/*navbar .navbar-nav {              == Comment out two lines ==
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}                                   == to center menu items ==*/

.navbar-default {                   /*navbar */
    background-color: #004C99;
    border-color: #004C99;
    z-index: 10;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {     /*Company/Port name*/
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {   /*Company/Port name hover*/
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {  /*navbar links*/
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {  /*navbar links hover*/
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00337e;
    transition: color 0.33s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {               /*Dropdown list*/
    color: #00337e !important;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover {         /*Dropdown list hover*/
    color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {  /*Dropdown open button*/
    background-color: #00337e;
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    padding: 0px;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: none !important;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block !important;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}
button.navbar-toggle {
    padding-bottom: 9px !important;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some of your code that you can add?

Answer (score 0):

you're going to need to remove the padding and width constraints on your nav parent elements. As you can see in this fiddle, there children extend the width of the nav with everything at 100% width and a max width on the parent element (if you need it) to constrain the menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/calebswank/1mb4n8db/

```
nav {
width: 100%;
max-width: 600px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
padding: 0;
```

}